# Assigning one object to another of the same class

Tags: c#, .net, variables, scope, instance

Please have a look at the code below:

```
class Parent{}

class Child : Parent
{
    public int field 
    {
        get; 
        set;
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Child child1 = new Child();
        Child child2 = child1;              //same memory address?

        child1.field = 12;
        child2.field = 14;

        Console.WriteLine(child1.field);    //14, as expected

        child1 = null;
        Console.WriteLine(child2.field);    //expected to crush: 'child1' is null so expected 'child2' to also be null

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

I expected this code to crash, but it does not not.

Why?

Comment: Still a reference in child2, then the object still exists!

Comment: Setting a variable to `null` doesn't destroy the object it pointed to. The object will only be destroyed (garbage collected) when there are no more references to it and the GC runs.

Comment: I guess what you are trying to do with `child1 = null;` actually `child1.Dispose();` ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

That's not how references work.

```
Child child1 = new Child();
```

creates a *reference* to a new `Child` object

```
Child child2 = child1;
```

Creates *another* reference that points to the same object that `child1` does

```
child1 = null;
```

Sets the `child1` *reference* to `null` (it no longer points to anything).  It does not change the object it pointed to and does not affect `child2`.  `child2` still points to the same object it did before.

Answer (score 4):

No, you are just setting the reference value contained in the child1 variable to the null value.
The second object instance still contains the original reference value and still works

In a very simplified way, when you write

```
Child child1 = new Child();
```

the `child1` instance is created in memory and a reference to it is returned with a value that we could represent as the value `1000`. This value (the reference) is assigned to the child1 variable

```
Child child2 = child1;
```

You assign the same reference value `1000` to the second variable

```
child1 = null;
```

You set the variable child1 the value zero (or whatever the implementers of null decide null to be), but the chidl2 still contains the reference value 1000.

Still having a valid reference to the memory area where the original object has been created correctly blocks the Garbage Collector from removing the object from memory and you could still safely use the second variable

Answer (score 4):

First you create a child object and assign it to the variable `child1`

```
Child child1 = new Child();
```

So you can think of it looking like this, `child1` points to an instance of a `Child` object

```
child1 ---->  { Child object }
```

Then you do this:

```
Child child2 = child1;
```

This copies the *reference* so now both variable points to the same object:

```
child1 ---->  { Child object }
child2 ------------^
```

Then you do this:

```
child1 = null;
```

This removes from the variable `child1` the reference to the instance of the `Child` object. The important point here is that the `Child` object itself is unaffected by this:

```
child1        { Child object }
child2 ------------^
```

So since `child2` had a *copy* of the reference, it is unaffected too and still points to the instance of `Child` you created at the start.

Answer (score 1):

Unlike value-typed variables, reference variables are **merely pointers towards an object instance**. You can have multiple variables pointing to the same object; setting one of them to `null` doesn't make the object itself unavailable. It's just as if you were saying "*now this doesn't point anywhere anymore*". Hence, it doesn't affect the instance, let alone the other variables that are still pointing to it.

In your code, what you did is setting `child1` variable to `null`, while `child2` was still pointing to your instance. Therefore, the code is perfectly valid and doesn't crash. I understand it may be confusing since the `field` property *did* change on both `child1` and `child2`, but it really does make sense when you realize they both point to the very same instance. At this point what really was affected wasn't `child1` or `child2` themselves; it's the `field` member of the `Child` instance both were referring to that was.

When no other pointers exists to your object instance, eventually the garbage collector clears it from memory. However, as long as something points to it and that pointer remains within scope, the instance isn't going anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Yes when you assign a object to another object of the same class, the memory address or the reference is same.

But when you do `child1=null;`, the `child2` still references the same object that it referenced during its initialization.